# Apache to understand <? as <?php

Tags: php, html, apache

Apache to understand

I have some code constructed at my old server

```
<? echo "hello world";?>
```

but when I migrate to new server

```
<? is not recognize, how do i set to recognize it as <?php
```

Thanks!

Comment: Enable php short tags

Comment: [In the config file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) enable short tags.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
short_open_tag = on
```

in `php.ini` and restart your Apache server.

If you don't have access to the php.ini you can try to enable them trough the `.htaccess` file but it's possible the hosting company disabled this if you are on shared hosting:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure php to use short tags

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).